# Parsing error: Unexpected token ReactJS Problem

Tags: reactjs, unexpected-token, parsing-error

I was new in ReactJS and I want to learn the basics from Traversy Media's video tutorial and I apply the code exactly what he have to do. But I got stuck [in this part](https://youtu.be/sBws8MSXN7A?t=1805) because I got an error Failed to Compile like this: 
[image: Failed to compile]

This is the code I have written:

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Todos from './components/Todos';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
   todos: [
     {
       id: 1,
       title: 'Take out he trash',
       completed: false
     },
     {
       id: 2,
       title: 'Have a Dinner',
       completed: false
     },
     {
       id: 3,
       title: 'Meeting with Boss',
       completed: false
     },
   ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Todos todos={this.state.todos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

### Todos.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TodoItem           from './TodoItem';

class Todos extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.todos.map((todo) => (
      <TodoItem/>
    ));
  }
}

export default Todos;
```

### TodoItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class TodoItem extends Component{
  render(){
    return{
      <div>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    }
  }
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It should look like that -**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class TodoItem extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
return(
  <div>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
)
```

Use braces for methods or variables

Comment: So it was my mistakes. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Okay please upvote this post to help others also... And so I can have some cool points

Comment: Or Check it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in TodoItem.js return statement. Just replace this code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

     export class TodoItem extends Component{
       render(){
         return(
           <div>
            <p>Hello</p>
           </div>
               )
             }
           }

      export default TodoItem;
```